# How to send email notifier with facebook php sdk?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i can do it via url:

https://api.facebook.com/method/notifications.sendEmail?recipients=ID_USER&subject=test&text=test&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail.

Comment: it's possible to do it with facebook php sdk? or i only can send a email notifier via url like above?

Comment: Like send a message via the SDK? Absolutely doable

Comment: can i do it or no? i don't understand u/\

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

EDIT:
I see now you are trying to use the PHP SDK. Perhaps something like the following will work for you (saw this on another stackoverflow question):

```
$parameters = array(
    'app_id' => $facebook->getAppId(),
    'to' => $facebookUserId,
    'link' => '(required) The link to send in the message. (??)',
    'redirect_uri' => 'URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO_AFTER_USER_CLICKS_SEND_OR_CANCEL',
    'picture' => 'OPTIONAL_URL_TO_IMG--AUTOGENERATED BY LINK',
    'name' => 'OPTIONAL_NAME_OF_MESSAGE/ARTICLE--AUTOGENERATED BY LINK',
    'description' => 'OPTIONAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT--AUTOGENERATED BY LINK'
 );
 $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?'.http_build_query($parameters);
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open('.json_encode($url).', "_blank", options, false);</script>';
```

Comment: sry but i don't mean it. I want to know how to send a email notifier like it https://api.facebook.com/method/notifications.sendEmail?recipients=ID_USER&subject=test&text=test&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN but with facebook sdk php